# What can be done to resolve this dependency issue?

Tags: haskell, cabal-install, bytestring, aeson

I'm trying to install `aeson` after resetting `~/.ghc` and `~/.cabal`.

`cabal install aeson` gives me the following error message:

```
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
next goal: aeson (user goal)
rejecting: aeson-0.9.0.1, 0.9.0.0, 0.8.1.1, 0.8.1.0 (global constraint
requires ==0.8.0.2)
trying: aeson-0.8.0.2
next goal: bytestring (user goal)
rejecting: bytestring-0.10.6.0, 0.10.4.1, 0.10.4.0, 0.10.2.0 (global
constraint requires installed instance)
rejecting: bytestring-0.10.0.2/installed-4f9... (conflict: aeson =>
bytestring>=0.10.4.0)
rejecting: bytestring-0.10.0.2, 0.10.0.1, 0.10.0.0, 0.9.2.1, 0.9.2.0,
0.9.1.10, 0.9.1.9, 0.9.1.8, 0.9.1.7, 0.9.1.6, 0.9.1.5, 0.9.1.4, 0.9.1.3,
0.9.1.2, 0.9.1.1, 0.9.1.0, 0.9.0.4, 0.9.0.3, 0.9.0.2, 0.9.0.1, 0.9 (global
constraint requires installed instance)
Dependency tree exhaustively searched.
```

The current version of `bytestring` package in my system is `0.10.2.0`. I tried `cabal install bytestring --reinstall` so that I can have a more recent version of bytestring (thereby solving aeson dependency issue). But that returns a very odd error:

```
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
next goal: bytestring (user goal)
rejecting: bytestring-0.10.6.0, 0.10.4.1, 0.10.4.0, 0.10.2.0, 0.10.0.2,
0.10.0.1, 0.10.0.0, 0.9.2.1, 0.9.2.0, 0.9.1.10, 0.9.1.9, 0.9.1.8, 0.9.1.7,
0.9.1.6, 0.9.1.5, 0.9.1.4, 0.9.1.3, 0.9.1.2, 0.9.1.1, 0.9.1.0, 0.9.0.4,
0.9.0.3, 0.9.0.2, 0.9.0.1, 0.9 (global constraint requires installed instance)
Dependency tree exhaustively searched.
```

I can solve the problem by using sandboxes. But I'm interested to know if there is a nicer method resolve the dependency issue.

---

**Update**: Following a suggestion, I removed `bytestring` by `ghc-pkg unregister --force bytestring`, which broke some packages and am still not able to install aeson.

Following is the output of `ghc-pkg list` lists: http://lpaste.net/135108.

Comment: `bytestring` is a dependency of `aeson`. So remove `bytestring` and install `aeson` itself.

Comment: @Sibi, I removed bytestring. Now `cabal install aeson` will point me to the second error (related to bytestring). Any suggestions?

Comment: Try `cabal install --reinstall --force-reinstalls aeson`

Comment: @thoferon, that didn't work. Gives me the second error (related to bytestring).

Comment: How did you remove `bytestring` ? Can you paste the output of `ghc-pkg list` ?

Comment: Did you modify your ~/.cabal/config file with constraints (possibly from a Stackage snapshot)? It looks like you have constraints in place which are incompatible with the GHC version you're using.

Comment: @Michael Snoyman, I had  `~/.cabal` removed, and have not modified anything.

Comment: Under normal circumstances, `cabal` does not apply a constraint for `bytestring` to use an installed instance. This constraint must come from somewhere. Either a cabal config file, or a sandbox, or a command line flag, or ...

Comment: Based on your ghc-pkg output it looks like you've been installing packages globally as root. This is a bad idea if you don't know what you're doing. You should delete and reinstall GHC completely and then install packages locally as a regular user.

Answer (score 1):

Where is your constraint (`global constraint
requires ==0.8.0.2`) coming from?

```
~/prog$ cd
~$ mkdir sbox
~$ cd sbox
~/sbox$ HOME=`pwd`
~$ export HOME
~$ cabal install bytestring
Config file path source is default config file.
Config file /home/novadenizen/sbox/.cabal/config not found.
Writing default configuration to /home/novadenizen/sbox/.cabal/config
Warning: The package list for 'hackage.haskell.org' does not exist. Run 'cabal
update' to download it.
cabal: There is no package named 'bytestring'.
You may need to run 'cabal update' to get the latest list of available
packages.
~$ cabal update
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
~$ cabal install aeson
Resolving dependencies...
Downloading bytestring-0.10.6.0...
Downloading dlist-0.7.1.1...
Configuring dlist-0.7.1.1...
Downloading syb-0.5.1...
Downloading transformers-0.4.3.0...
Configuring syb-0.5.1...
Building dlist-0.7.1.1...
Building syb-0.5.1...
Installed dlist-0.7.1.1
Configuring bytestring-0.10.6.0...
Building bytestring-0.10.6.0...
Configuring transformers-0.4.3.0...
Installed syb-0.5.1
Building transformers-0.4.3.0...
Installed transformers-0.4.3.0
Downloading mtl-2.2.1...
Downloading primitive-0.6...
Configuring primitive-0.6...
Building primitive-0.6...
Configuring mtl-2.2.1...
Installed primitive-0.6
Downloading vector-0.10.12.3...
Building mtl-2.2.1...
Configuring vector-0.10.12.3...
Installed mtl-2.2.1
Building vector-0.10.12.3...
Installed bytestring-0.10.6.0
Downloading binary-0.7.5.0...
Configuring binary-0.7.5.0...
Building binary-0.7.5.0...
Installed binary-0.7.5.0
Downloading text-1.2.1.1...
Configuring text-1.2.1.1...
Building text-1.2.1.1...
Installed vector-0.10.12.3
Installed text-1.2.1.1
Downloading hashable-1.2.3.2...
Configuring hashable-1.2.3.2...
Building hashable-1.2.3.2...
Installed hashable-1.2.3.2
Downloading scientific-0.3.3.8...
Downloading unordered-containers-0.2.5.1...
Configuring scientific-0.3.3.8...
Configuring unordered-containers-0.2.5.1...
Building scientific-0.3.3.8...
Building unordered-containers-0.2.5.1...
Installed scientific-0.3.3.8
Downloading attoparsec-0.13.0.0...
Configuring attoparsec-0.13.0.0...
Building attoparsec-0.13.0.0...
Installed unordered-containers-0.2.5.1
Installed attoparsec-0.13.0.0
Downloading aeson-0.9.0.1...
Configuring aeson-0.9.0.1...
Building aeson-0.9.0.1...
Installed aeson-0.9.0.1
~$
```